# Azure service fabric - Performance telemetry of individual service

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to get the performance telemetry of an individual service running in a node which has other services running in the same node within  a servive fabric cluster?

We are using .net core where there are not performance counters either and we arent using containers at the moment. We want to make sure one microservice doesnt hog all the system resources and choke the other microservices running in the same node. We are using guest executables.

Comment: Are you using app insights? We currently use a WebApi front-end followed by some stateless and stateful services. The AppInsights integration in the WebApi is painless, but getting appinsights into the microservices is a little more cumbersome, but it does provide some performance information you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for that. Yeah the plan is to use app insights. But we werent sure if it would ship system level performance data but at a individual service level. Let me try that

Comment: I think it does performance at the process level, so in theory, it should show only the insights for that process. From our own stats, each of our services have really low utilization, and are all different, so this should be how it is working.

Answer (score 1):

We use application insight. It has support for microservices for service fabric ie correlation id where you can trace a request through multiple services within service fabric

Here is set up instruction and example 
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric